# Ориентация Activity

Tags: android

Как сделать так что бы Activity было только в портретном режиме и при повороте экрана не менялось на горизонтальное ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<activity
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
</activity>
```